# X11VNC performance - QQuickView vs QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: qt, qml, x11, qqmlapplicationengine, qquickview

I am running a QML application and using X11VNC to remotely view the output. When the QML application uses `QQmlApplicationEngine`, I am only able to see 2-5 frames per second on the VNC viewer whereas when I use `QQuickView`, I am able to see 8-10 frames per second.

Since `QQmlApplicationEngine` is newer than `QQuickView`, one would naturally assume that it is more powerful. What could be the reason for the behavior I am seeing?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You can use xrdp instead of vnc server , vnc has a little bit problem with x11 desktop

Comment: I've had encountered problems with vnc server before in Kubuntu 17.04

Comment: Newer is not always synonymous to better. New frequently means immature, and lack of maturity can reflect negatively on performance, efficiency, features and stability.

Comment: Don't think that update rate for VNC frames is somehow dependent on class you use. Maybe framerate of your Qt application suffers when you use `QQmlApplicationEngine`?